# Audio question - loading multiple files silently and using faders

Tags: audio, browser, twine

Weird question, I apologise in advance.

I'm using Twine 1.4.2 to create music lessons for students. (Remote learning and Covid. It's such a drag.) https://twinery.org/

I jiggered the music macros from here, https://www.glorioustrainwrecks.com/node/5061, to make the 'loopsound' macro into a thing where I could loop multiple .oggs on passages at 0 volume. Then I could use 'fadeinsound' and 'fadeoutsound' like faders on a mixer - so a passage could fade a stem in, or out. The tracks all looped simultaneously, so it was like one big piece of music, with stems being faded in or out - when you went to the next web page.

This worked for several years - on almost all browsers. It's broken recently. Not sure why. Something to do with how audio files are loaded and browsers changing up their conventions? This Twine code has preload written into it.

Anyway. I was thinking of trying to do rewrite myself, with the audio element. I do not have the chops.

This is where I'm at. So, on the first passage (like a web page), I've got ...

```
<audio preload>
<source src="c1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="c2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="c3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>`<audio preload>


<audio preload>
<source src="f1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="f2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="f3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

The 3 cs are supposed to loop in line. And the 3 fs.

On the next passage I have ...

```
<audio loop autoplay id="c1">
<source src="c1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
<audio loop autoplay id="c1">
<source src="c2.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio> 
<audio loop autoplay id="c1">
<source src="c3.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
```

This works. All of these play in line. (Like, not out of time with each other.)

So ...

1. How do I get them to all loop at zero volume?
2. How would I then get them to fade in or out at current time - on a new page? (Like, without restarting the track.)

Any help appreciated! Hopefully that made sense. It's a weird, niche project, really.

Thanks!

Meg

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

Sort of. In case anyone comes looking for anything this weird in the future.

Couldn't use the audio element at all because each passage is a separate page. Had to rearrange the order of the macros within Twine. I know what I did, but I have no idea how to explain it.

If someone really does come looking for this in the future (probably one of my students - hello), post and I'll try to explain.

PS. Full credit to L for the macro code. I just messed with it. (I just made the loops play at 0 volume and not restart after fadeout. https://www.glorioustrainwrecks.com/node/5061